# Error when executing npm install @types\selenium-webdriver-93afec84\package.json

Tags: angular, angular5, npm-install

error when executing npm install:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN codelyzer@3.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@3.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path F:\SOLUTION\node_modules\.staging\@types\selenium-webdriver-93afec84\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\SOLUTION\node_modules\.staging\@types\selenium-webdriver-93afec84\package.json'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "reprografia",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve –o --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "fixed-ng2-sticky-kit": "^2.1.7",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.27",
    "mydatepicker": "^2.5.0",
    "ng2-auto-complete": "^0.12.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^1.6.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53", 
    "@types/node": "~8.0.19",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.7.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

May be some ideas to fix it?